# Coordinate formatting for swath data - to polygon

Tags: csv, import, coordinate-system, lidar, format

I've got a CSV of Lidar coverage swaths in the below format. Each run or strip is tied together via run_id. I'm assuming L is for left, R is for right and M is for middle.

EDIT: These are coordinates extracted from our flight software's database to an Excel table of the swath boundaries; this is not actual lidar data, just the outlines of what was flown and recorded.

How would I format this for easy import into QGIS, Arc, or Global Mapper as polygons?

```
    Polygons from Left, Right and middle point coordinates-swath.jpg
```

[image: Swath_Data]

Comment: as LAS data or something different?

Comment: To CSV ideally. I just cant figure out how to get this data into a format that is readable as Polygons.

Comment: normally you read lidar into software as raster type and process to polygon from there. do some reading on lidar import.

Comment: I guess I did not explain my situation too well. These are coordinates extracted from our flight software's database to an excel table of the swath boundaries, this is not actual lidar data, just the outlines of what was flown and recorded.

Comment: please don't add comments to further explain your question. hit the edit button and add more information.

Comment: Done, wasn't sure what the etiquette was here

Comment: No problem it is good for me to get back to help and read what that is... http://gis.stackexchange.com/help  http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/stackexchange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have one data value per line, I suggest to take the middle coordinates, and import coordinates and value as point data.

In a second run, you can interpolate the data of different runs into a raster, if they are neatless.

---

**UPDATE**

If you are only interested in the swath polygon, I suggest to import the left and right coordinates in two runs as lines using the MMQGIS plugin of QGIS, then connect them manually.

Otherwise you would have to go down the left coordinates to the last entry, then backwards through the records for the right coordinates to get a cloesd line.

Comment: MMQGIS was my missing link. That gets me a lot closer to what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option using ArcGIS if the point data is regularly spaced:

1. Create a feature class (fc) for each of the coordinate x/y pairs (R,M,L)
2. Merge fc together from step 1
3. Use [Create Fishnet](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000002q000000) tool to create polygon layer (you will have to define the number of columns and rows or cell height/width value)
4. You may have to do some clean up using various topology methods to get the polygon vertexes snapped to the fc points